# FIRESTORE: Query collectionGroup by Document ID

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Now we have collection group queries on firestore! Great.

But due to some rules, how can one query a collection group by Document ID?

I tried:

```
return this.afs.collectionGroup('tokens', (ref) => {
      return ref.where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', `${this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid}`)
    }).valueChanges();
```

But I get:

```
Invalid third parameter to Query.where(). When querying a collection group by FieldPath.documentId(), the value provided must result in a valid document path, but 'JKq2AFqGkkSLHsIVaXz4l3wwmfh1' is not because it has an odd number of segments (1).
```

I also tried:

```
return this.afs.collectionGroup('tokens', (ref) => {
      return ref.where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', `/users/JKq2AFqGkkSLHsIVaXz4l3wwmfh1`)
    }).valueChanges();
```

But then I get 0 results

My tokens collection document ID's are based on my `/users/{userID}`

The rules I have for the tokens collection are:

```
 match /{path=**}/tokens/{userID} {
            allow read, write, create, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userID;
    }
```

For example this is the document I need to get

```
/suuntoAppAccessTokens/dimitrioskanellopoulos/tokens/JKq2AFqGkkSLHsIVaXz4l3wwmfh1
```

Of course if I use:

```
return this.afs.collectionGroup('tokens', (ref) => {
      return ref.where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', `/suuntoAppAccessTokens/dimitrioskanellopoulos/tokens/JKq2AFqGkkSLHsIVaXz4l3wwmfh1`)
    }).valueChanges();
```

it works but that beats the point of the collection group queries

So is there any way to query a collection group by document ID and not path + document id ?